# What are some resources I can follow to create a program that writes an XML file using STREAM?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, stream

This is for my schoolwork. I need to write from my data to an XML file, invoiceData.xml using the STREAM method. I have done a program that reads from an XML file using the DOM method if telling you about it helps. :)

So please help me, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  I did it in one instruction last week : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644335/how-do-i-write-to-invoicedata-xml-using-stream-using-these-data-stated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write to invoiceData.xml using STREAM using these data stated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644335/how-do-i-write-to-invoicedata-xml-using-stream-using-these-data-stated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @MarkGravell in other answer, `XmlSerializer` is better choice.

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlSerializerNamespaces.Add("", "");

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, BufferSize, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
    xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, xmlWriterSettings);
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, yourClassInstance, xmlSerializerNamespaces);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the mid level:

```
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream)) { /* your code here */ }
```

and you're set; however, I would argue that even this is unnecessarily over-complicating things for most scenarios. If you have the data in memory, it would me more typical to just ask `XmlSerializer` to worry about that:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
ser.Serialize(stream, obj);
```

So: google `XmlSerializer` and `XmlWriter` :) both are on MSDN